# Code::Blocks - warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb, codeblocks

I've installed Code::Blocks 13.12 in Ubuntu 14.04 through official repositories. When I compile, everything goes OK. But when I debug, the following message is shown at the shell:

> warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not
>   permitted

And the program is executed up to the breaking point, but nothing more is shown when I execute the next lines.

How to fix this?

PD: I've installed the latest version of GDB (the one which is in repositories). I've also tried to use the linux terminal instead of the one Codeblocks shows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ubuntu codeblocks :warning: GDB： Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841727/ubuntu-codeblocks-warning-gdb-failed-to-set-controlling-terminal-operation-n)

Answer (score 6):

I think this just means that code::blocks is running gdb in "CLI" mode without making a pseudo-terminal.  So, when gdb tries terminal operations, they fail.  You can just ignore these messages.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, this problem still exists in 2020...

I've installed Code::Blocks 1.6 on clear CentOS 7 installation and got the same messages and behavior.

For me, this is solved by disabling SELinux which prevented IDE from using debugger.

Answer (score -8):

Add :

*system("Pause")*

and it will work

Comment: Please clarify.  Add: system("Pause") to what.