# GDB debugger doesn't work in Code::blocks

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

*Information:* 
*OS: Ubuntu 14.04* 
*IDE: Code::blocks 13.12* 
*Debugger: gdb 7.10*

I'm new to code::blocks and was trying out the debugger, but it didn't work. So I'm here to ask you what I could do to find a solution to this problem.

When I click on 'step into' and the XTerm console opens with the message:

> warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling teminal: Operation not permitted

And the output is not to be seen anywhere.

Comment: Why do you think it didn't work? Have you tried to set breakpoints? What do you expect to see?

Comment: I think it didn't work because nothing of what the program should output can be seen in the console, but if run the program normally then I can read the expected output.
The breakpoint changes nothing and the program should output the classic "Hello World!".

Comment: UPDATE: if there is an endl after the last cout, then I can see every the correct output.
So I'd say that the problem is solved :D

Comment: @Sven If you have solved your problem, you should either delete this useless content, or consider to write an answer for your question yourself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you find the way I edited the question ok?
I decided the leave the post so that other people with the same dumb problem will find the solution.

Comment: @Sven remove the STATUS SOLVED from your title please, and move the whole update part from your body to the **Your Answer** edit box below. Then it's OK I think. After a while (2 days IIRC) you can mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you really much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ubuntu codeblocks :warning: GDB： Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841727/ubuntu-codeblocks-warning-gdb-failed-to-set-controlling-terminal-operation-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found out there was no real problem, I only had to end the line that I was trying to see with a 'endl'

What I was trying to execute in the debugging session, but couldn't see:

```
 cout << "Hello World!";
```

What solved the problem, enabling me to see the output in the debugger:

```
 cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to flush your buffered streams (ie. `fflush` for `FILE*`, and `.flush` for `std::stream`-s).

But you don't need any IDE to run `gdb`. You could run it in a plain terminal, try `gdb` or `gdb -tui` or [`gdb --args` or in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984938/841108)